# How to resize y axis of a dendogram

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I am using  `scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch` to draw a dendogram after makeing an hierarchical clustering. The problem is that the clustering happens on the top of the dendogram in between 0.8 and 1.0 which is the similarity degree in the y axis. How can i "cut" all the graph from 0 to 0.6 where nothing "interesting" graphically is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If your're really only interested in distance proportions *between* the fusions, you could

- adapt your input linkage (cut off an offset in the third column of the linkage matrix). This will screw the absolute cophenetic distances of course.
- do some normalization of your input data, before clustering it

Or you

- manipulate the dendrogram axes / adapt limits (I didn't try that)